# How-to generate a stacked BarChart?

Tags: plotting, charts

I would like to generate a stacked `BarChart` using following sudo dataset.

```
data = {
   {2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 1, 3, 4},
   {3, 1, 2.5, 2.5},
   {3, 2}
   };
```

In essence, I want to get the `BarChart` to display the `Tally` of the sublists in a logically consistent way.

[image]

This is the code I am experimenting with

```
BarChart[
 (* data *)
 , PlotTheme -> "Classic"
 , BarOrigin -> Left
 , Joined -> True
 , LabelingFunction -> Center
 , ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
 , ChartLabels -> {Map[Style[#, 12] &, {"x", "y", "z", "e", "d"}], 
   None}
 , ChartLegends -> {1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4}
 ]
```

Note, I have tried doing it with `RectangleChart` using following code as example...

```
RectangleChart[
 Tally /@  data
 , ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
]
```

However, I couldn't get the rectangles to be same size on 'x' axes.

Comment: You mean that the boxes should all be of the same size, or what is the problem with your example bar chart?

Comment: @C.E. I want to `Tally` the sublists and have the bars in the `BarChart` display the resuls of the tally. `RactangleChart` almost does it all for me. Except, I would like all boxes visually to be the same length across 'x' axes.

Comment: @C.E, I have uploaded a visual of what I want to achieve

Comment: thank you, it's very clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
minmax = MinMax[data];

labeleddata = (Labeled[Style[#2, ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax}]@#], 
        Row[{#, " (", #2, ")"}], Center] & @@@ SortBy[First]@#) & /@ 
   Tally /@ data;

BarChart[labeleddata, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using the `"Classic"` color scheme:

```
union = Union[Flatten[data]];

cF = Blend[Transpose[{union, Charting`CommonDump`rogerStyles[Length@union]}], #] &;

labeleddata2 = (Labeled[Style[#2, cF @ #], Row[{#, " (", #2, ")"}], 
        Center] & @@@ SortBy[First]@#) & /@ Tally /@ data;

BarChart[labeleddata2, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for getting involved. How could I achieve consistency in color? For example, how could I get 1 to be purple, 2 green, 2.5 yellow, 3 orange, and 4 red?

Comment: @e.doroskevic, please see the updated version.

Comment: this is what I was looking for :D I just need to now figure out how to get the same color schema as in "classic" `PlotTheme`. Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, there should be a button to give extra points, or send $ for coffee as a form of gratitude, here on StackExchange. I am grateful for your help. Thank you!